# Why is $S^3$ $3$-dimensional?

Tags: general-topology

Why is the $3$-sphere $S^3$ $3$-dimensional and not $4$-dimensional? We use the standard definition of $S^{n}=\{(x_0,\ldots,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}\}$.
Note: They had written things like submanifold, but i didnt understand

Another question is $I^2$ homeomorphic to a torus ?

Comment: Do you understand why $S^1$ is $1$-dimensional or $S^2$ is $2$-dimensional? Pretend you lived on the surface of $S^2$: then you could either walk along a line of latitude or a line of latitude and these are the "only" distinct directions. $S^3$ is harder to visualize, but it locally looks like $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 1):

It is locally $3$-dimensional (it is a $3$-manifold). Globally you would have to define some notion of dimension first.

No it is not. One reason is the hole of the torus. More formally, these spaces habe different invariants as for example different fundamental groups.

Comment: if we would take the boundary of I^2, then it would be the same right ?

Comment: No, the boundary of $I^2$ is homeomorphic to a $1$-sphere, not a torus. But you can construct a torus out of $I^2$ by identifying the boundary in a specific way.

Answer (score 1):

It's locally $3$-dimensional: Each point as a neighborhood homeomorphic (or diffeomorphic, etc.) to $\mathbb{R}^3$. Less formally, each point needs three coordinates to describe it locally: if you know $x_1, x_2, x_3$, then $x_4 = \pm \sqrt{1 - x_1^2 - x_2^2 - x_3^2}$. (It's not uniquely determined by the other $x_i$, which is why the coordinates are only local.) It happens to have a nice embedding in a $4$-dimensional space, but that doesn't make it $4$-dimensional itself. A line in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is still $1$-dimensional, even though it's sitting in an $n$-dimensional space.

Although they're both $2$-manifolds, $I^2$ and the torus $S^1\times S^1$ are not the same. The former is contractible, while $S^1\times S^1$ is not; they have different homology and homotopy; $I^2$ is a manifold with boundary, while $S^1\times S^1$ is closed, and so on.

Comment: really dunno, why i did get a downgrade.. so it is only locally, got it. Well, i thoguht of linear algebra R^4 being 4 dimensional...but you can still make a "donut" of I^2 which seems to me the same as a standrd torus .

Comment: if we would take the boundary, then it would be the same right ?

Comment: $I^2$ is the solid square. Its boundary is (homeomorphic to) $S^1$, the unit circle. In particular, the boundary is a $1$-dimensional manifold, while the torus $S^1\times S^1$ is $2$-dimensional.

Comment: @Maths If we take a *quotient* of $I^2$, namely *identifying* (or '*gluing*') the points $(x,0)\sim (x, 1)$ and $(0,y)\sim(1,y)$ for all $x,y\in I$, *then* it's indeed the torus we receive, at least topologically.

Comment: yes exactly, quotienttopology is key. @berci